# How to replace m part of Lines with n part of Lines?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, grep

I have a file "test" like this:

```
RewiteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.7$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.8$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.9$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   ^192\.168\.1\.5$  [NC]
</Directory>
```

I want to replace `\.1\.7`,`\.1\.8` and `\.1\.9` by `\.1\.10` so it will be:

```
RewiteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.10$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   ^192\.168\.1\.5$  [NC]
</Directory>
```

it might be replacement of m "IPS" by n "IPS", How can I reach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `perl` solution:

```
$ perl -ple 's/\\\.1\\\.(7|8|9)/\\.1\\.10/' file | uniq
RewiteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.10$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   ^192\.168\.1\.5$  [NC]
</Directory>
```

If you want edit inplace, you can try:

```
perl -i.bak -nle 'next if $count and /!\^/;s/\\\.1\\\.(7|8|9)/\\.1\\.10/ and $count++ if /!\^/;print' file
```

Comment: Thanks, but are there other ways without using `perl`

Comment: @Networker All `perl` is doing here is regex substitution. You can use `sed` in the same way if you don't like `perl` (and if you don't, shame on you!)

Comment: @JosephR., I like perl (I like all scripting language indeed) but I want to benefit from `Gnouc` in more than one way.

Comment: @Gnouc, How can I make this changes inline (something like `-i` in `sed` )

Comment: @Networker: `perl -i.bak -pe ...`

Comment: @Gnouc, I ended up with three duplicated line

Comment: @Networker: Yes, you must use `uniq` to remove duplicated.

Comment: @Gnouc,I have used `uniq` like this:`perl -i.bak -ple 's/\\\.1\\\.(7|8|9)/\\.1\\.10/' test2 | uniq`

Comment: @Networker: `perl -ple 's/\\\.1\\\.(7|8|9)/\\.1\\.10/' test2 | uniq > newfile`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16198/discussion-between-networker-and-gnouc).

Comment: A more readable (for certain definitions of "readable") version of the regex could be: `s/\Q\.1\.\E\K(7|8|9)/10/`

Comment: @JosephR.: Nice one! Forgot about `\Q`, `\E`

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to do this by deleting all the lines and reinserting them, but I want an optimal solution (because here is deleting the whole line then adding a new whole line) and I want to add white spaces to the added lines:

delete:

```
sed -i '/!^.*$/d' test2
```

insert back:

```
 sed -i '/RewiteEngine On/aRewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.10$  [NC]' test2
```

the output is:

```
  RewiteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192.168.1.10$  [NC] # need whites spaces at the begining
  RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   ^192\.168\.1\.5$  [NC]
```

Answer (score 2):

A way with `gawk`:

```
awk '{gsub(/\.[7-9]\$/,"\.10$")}!a[$0]++' test
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but can you explain how the command worked and how can I make the change inline (inside the file).

Comment: If should be `awk '{gsub(/\\\.[7-9]/, "\\.10")} !a[$0]++' file`

Comment: @Srini no it shouldn't

Comment: your code will remove '.' and it will replace even if there is no '\' before the number... 
`echo '!^192\.168\.1\.7$
!^192\.168\.1.7$' | awk '{gsub(/\.[7-9]\$/,"10$")}!a[$0]++'`
will give you
`!^192\.168\.1\10$
!^192\.168\.110$`

Comment: It's not supposed to check for a \ before a number. It did leave a `.` out though so i've changed that

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '/!/d;/\(\^[^5]*\)./{h;s//!\110/p;g;}' <<\DATA
RewiteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.7$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.8$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.9$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   ^192\.168\.1\.5$  [NC]
</Directory>
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT

```
RewiteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.10$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   ^192\.168\.1\.5$  [NC]
</Directory>
```

So this relies on the `s/ubsti/tution/` matching the last address - which it will do. When an `/address/` is empty like `s//` or `//` the previous address is implied. It deletes all of `/!/` lines containing a bang, then it addresses on a line with a `^` and puts that into hold-space. Then it edits it, `p`rints it, and overwrites it again with its original value still in `h`old space.

But if the match address could match the `h`old line *and* the edited lines, then you could just keep editing them. Maybe like this:

```
sed '/!/d;/\(\^[^$]*\.\)[0-9]*/{h;s//!\110/p;s//\111/p;s//\112/p;g;}' <<\DATA
RewiteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.7$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.8$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.9$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   ^192\.168\.1\.5$  [NC]
</Directory>
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT

```
RewiteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.10$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.11$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.12$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   ^192\.168\.1\.5$  [NC]
</Directory>
```

Honestly, though, anymore than that and you'd probably want to approach it a little differently. Maybe with `printf`?

```
ips() { printf 's//\\1%d/p;' $(seq "$@") ; echo 'g;}' ; }

sed '/!/d;/\(\^[^$]*\.\)[0-9]*/{h;s//!\110/p;'"$(ips 11 30)" <<\DATA
RewiteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.7$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.8$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.9$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   ^192\.168\.1\.5$  [NC]
</Directory>
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT

```
RewiteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.10$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.11$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.12$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.13$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.14$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.15$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.16$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.17$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.18$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.19$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.20$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.21$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.22$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.23$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.24$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.25$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.26$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.27$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.28$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.29$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   !^192\.168\.1\.30$  [NC]
RewriteCond   %{REMOTE_ADDR}   ^192\.168\.1\.5$  [NC]
</Directory>
```

Comment: good one what if we want to replace  `\.1\.7`,`\.1\.8` and `\.1\.9` by `\.1\.10` and `\.1\.11`

Comment: @Networker - if you modify it just a little bit to make the addresss more generic - slightly - like `/\(\^[^$]*\.\)[0-9]*/` <that, then you can just keep on printing out new lines like `s//!\110/p;s//\111/p;g` and so on.

Comment: can you update your answer with new updates :)

Comment: @Networker - mission accomplished.

Comment: @mikesev, amazing answer and amazing explanation thanks :)